# Solve some unusual log/exponential equations

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, exponential-function

I understand about log and exponential equations/functions, but I can't solve these (the numbers are just examples, of course):

$ 4^x = x + 10$
$x^x = 3$
$(2x + 3x^2)^{x + 1} = (x - x^3)^{x^2}$

Are there specific algebraic steps that I can follow so that I solve them? Or, if not, what are the other means to find $x$ in each?

Comment: do you know about the Lambert W function?

Comment: I didn't, but I am looking it up right now. It seems pretty interesting, and way more complex than I imagined...

Comment: Are you looking for analytical solutions (which involve, as told, Lambert function) or for numerical solutions (which would involve Newton procedures) ? If the latest is of any interest tou you, let me know and I shall develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Start reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). The second problem is solved [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_2). As for the first one, here it goes:

$$4^x=x+10\quad|\cdot(-1)\cdot4^{-(x+10)}\iff-4^{-10}=-(x+10)\cdot4^{-(x+10)}\quad|\cdot\ln4\iff$$

$$-4^{-10}\ln4=-(x+10)\ln4\cdot e^{-(x+10)\ln4}\iff-(x+10)\ln4=W(-4^{-10}\ln4)\iff$$

$$x=-\frac{W(-4^{-10}\ln4)}{\ln4}-10.$$

And similarly for the third.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will research about the W function, and hopefully improve my math knowledge with this amazing solutions.